# Inheriting default methods with the same name in the class without any compilation error

Tags: java-8

How a class can implement two interfaces with the same default method in Java 8.
I was not able to get the concept behind the same default method from different interfaces getting inherited in the sub class.Please explain the issue.

```
interface House {
    default String getAddress() {
        return "101 Main Str";
    }
}

interface Bungalow extends House {
    default String getAddress() {
        return "101 Smart Str";
    }
}

class MyHouse implements Bungalow, House {

}

public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        House ci = new MyHouse();  //1
        System.out.println(ci.getAddress()); //2
    }
}
```

In the above code `default` method `getAddress()` in interface House is present.another method with the same name is declared as default in the extending interface Bungalow

How class `MyHouse` can implement both the interfaces without any compilation error(because it doesn't know which method has the preference in that case implementing should fail.)

If i call `new MyHouse().getAddress()`; gives compile error but it should give compilation error even without method calling from MyHouse class.

Comment: `Bungalow.getAddress()` overrides `House.getAddress()`. There is no reason for a compiler error and on my machine, I don’t get a compiler error.

Comment: @Holger,Thank you, yes,Bungalow overrides getAddress in House but MyHouse implementing both the House and Bungalow interfaces which should give a compile error without as it can access two methods with the same name.Why there is such an exceptional case?

Comment: What do you mean with “can access two methods with the same name”? It *inherits* two methods with the same name and type, which wouldn’t be different if the two methods were abstract. Since one of these methods overrides the other, it is also clear, which method will be called.

Answer (score 2):

It *seems* that the answer is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4.1), where there is a different example, but sort of makes sense and is really close to yours.

Ask me *the exact same thing* in 1/2 a year and I'll say it will fail at compile time and point me to this answer, so that I could read the JLS again. I guess this is how they decided to implement it. Without thinking too much, I, personally (may be wrong) think that this is at least counter intuitive...

Comment: So, you understood the question, resp. could reproduce the compiler error the OP is talking about?

Comment: @Holger no, I assumed `interface Bungalow` without the extends - compilation error, with `extends` - no. I assumed the second...

Comment: The OP clearly said “in the extending interface Bungalow”. But anyway, when `Bungalow` is not extending `House`, you will get a compilation error at the declaration of `class MyHouse`, but the OP is talking about a compilation error on `new MyHouse().getAddress()`. Which does not happen in either case.

Comment: @Holger you are right, reading this again makes sense from your point. I guess I just got focused away since I instantly thought it will fail with a compilation error, before trying...